# How do I stop Tkinter diologs from lowering window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to create a basic GUI. I have a main window (let's say window A) that opens a second window (window B). Window B has a file dialog message, and a few messageboxes. Whenever these open, they automatically lower window B behind window A. How do I prevent this?

Here are two scripts relating to the two windows.
a.py creates window A, and opens b.py:

```
# a.py
import tkinter as tk
import b


def open_b():
    b.open_me()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('a')
button = tk.Button(window, text='open b', command=open_b)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and b.py creates window B, which can create a messagebox.

```
# b.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def open_me():

    def warning():
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', f"I just lowered window B below window A")

    top_window = tk.Toplevel()
    top_window.title('b')
    warning_button = tk.Button(top_window, text='open dialog', command=warning)
    warning_button.pack()

    top_window.mainloop()
```

As you can see, when the "open b" button is clicked on window A, window B is created on top of it. Then if you click the "open dialog" button on window B, a messagebox is created, but it pushes window B below window A.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter message.showinfo() takes me back to the first window rather than staying on the window where the button is situated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562329/tkinter-message-showinfo-takes-me-back-to-the-first-window-rather-than-staying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you haven't specified the parent of the `messagebox`, by default it assumes the root (`window` in your case) and hence will push other toplevels down when called. To get around this specify the `parent` option.

```py
messagebox.showwarning('Warning', f"I just lowered window B below window A",parent=top_window)
```